# 3SLS with fixed effects and its interpretation issue

Tags: stata, bias, simultaneity

I am running empirical models based on 3SLS due to the potential endogeneity issue caused by simultaneity. So, I opted for 3SLS as my main analysis tool, and I am using reg3 command to analyze it. My model and STATA command are as below.

Empirical model: DV = intercept + endog_var1 + control1 +  ... + control6 + i.industry + i.year + error term (In this model, I assume that there is only one endogenous variable because I am only interested in var1, and there could be potentially simultaneity bias between DV and var1 due to the unobservable factors that affect both, and I am planning to relieve the bias by using one instrument.)

STATA command: reg3 (DV endog_var1 control1 control2 control3 control4 control5 control6 i.industry i.Year) (endog_var1 DV instrument1 i.industry i.Year)

Actually, when I run fixed effects models that have opposite DV and endog_var1 as DV and IV, respectively, (i.e., model 1: DV = intercept + endog_var1 + control1 +  ... + control6 + i.industry + i.year + error term & model 2: endog var1 = intercept + DV + control1 +  ... + control6 + i.industry + i.year + error term), either way, I could find that the coefficients of DV and endog_var1 are quite statistically significant.

However, if I run the STATA command above, I could only see significant endog_var1 in the second stage, but DV becomes insignificant (p-value > 0.1) in the first-stage (second parentheses in reg3) in the 3SLS model.

To sum up, my questions are fourfold.

1. Should I also put all the control variables into the first stage (second parantheses in reg3 model) in 3SLS model? (However, I keep getting a warning like equation is not identified—does not meet order conditions.
2. How to interpret when DV becomes insignificant after running the 3SLS model? (endog_var1 DV instrument1 i.industry i.Year; Here, DV is not significant.)
3. If I want to add fixed effects into the model, how could I add them to the STATA command?
4. What if I set up a model like reg3 (DV endog_var1 control1 control2 control3 control4 control5 control6 i.industry i.Year) (endog_var1 instrument1 i.industry i.Year) without DV in the first stage. Does this model still cope with simultaneity bias that my model might have?

Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions that must be answered before applying your model:

a) **Are you sure Endogeneity will be an issue?** You mentioned a 'potential' endogeneity issue meaning you suspect it might be a problem. You can verify it with a Hausman Test of Endogeneity. It is possible that simultaneity/endogeneity may not be a serious issue, then you won't need models like 2SLS or 3SLS.

b) **Are the time-specific effects or cross-sectional effects significant?** If they are not, you don't need fixed effects in the model. If significant, you must decide whether fixed effects or random effects are appropriate.

c) **Do you really need to apply 3SLS?** You need 3SLS only if the error terms are correlated across equations of your simultaneous equation model. If they are not correlated across equations, 3SLS boils down to a 2SLS model. So, you are better off applying 2SLS.

Moving on to your questions:

**1), 2) & 4)** The control variables must be included in the first stage. And, you do not need to include DV in the first stage. The first stage represents the reduced-form equations, which means that all the endogenous variables are taken as dependent and only the exogenous variables (including controls and instruments) are used as independent variables. The warning that you get about the equation not being identified happens because you have included DV in the first stage, which is making your equation under-identified.

**3)** You have already included i.industry and i.Year as independent variables. They act as fixed effects because you are including cross-sectional dummies (i.industry) and time-specific dummies (i.Year) in your model.

The following links discuss some of these issues in more detail:

3SLS: https://spureconomics.com/3sls-three-stage-least-squares/

2SLS: https://spureconomics.com/two-stage-least-squares-2sls-estimation/

Identification: https://spureconomics.com/identification-rank-and-order-conditions/

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ideas. I have a follow-up question regarding the first point you mentioned. I have tested DWH tests (estat endog/test residual according to microeconomics using STATA, 2nd ed.) using the instrument variable that I was planning to use in 3SLS, and got the insignificant result (p-value > 0.1). It seems that my model doesn't suffer from an endogeneity issue. Then, would it be possible to say that my empirical models do not have to take into account endogeneity solely on the basis of the result of DWH tests?

Comment: Theoretically, it is plausible to suspect that there might be endogeneity due to simultaneity because DV and endog_var1 in my empirical model are basically operational performance of two partners in a dyadic relationship. I am still wondering if I should rely on a theoretical base or statistical analysis to decide whether or not I am going to do IV approach. Thank you, and I will look forward to hearing from you again.

Comment: Theoretically, you suspect that endogeneity might be an issue. So it is essential to check for it. But, the data you are working with does not show signs of any serious endogeneity issue according to the Hausman test. Another thing you can do is compare the results of 2SLS and OLS. How different are they? If endogeneity is a problem, OLS coefficients will be biased and very different from 2SLS. In any case, you have a valid reason to believe that endogeneity is not a severe problem in your dataset/model and you can show the Hausman test results to support it.